# Recommendations for ajax component libraries

Tags: ajax, components, uicomponents

If I were to pick an AJAX component library to focus on for general web development, with good grid support and wide range of components, which would you recommend and why?

I started with the following list, based on the fact that they're included in the google libraries API:

- [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/)
- [Ext Core](http://extjs.com/products/extcore/)
- [MooTools](http://mootools.net/)
- [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/)
- [Prototype scriptaculous](http://prototypejs.org/) (What's the diff?)
- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com) on [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) and [jQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).

As far as I know only [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/) offers a grid component, Ext Core doesn't.

script.aculo.us is pretty much an addon library for Prototype.